# Anime where soldiers are fighting in a forest wearing futuristic armor

Tags: story-identification, anime

Back in the early 2000s I was given a VHS that had a compilation of different anime on it. This one I remember fondly is where these two soldiers were fighting in a forest wearing futuristic armor and the antagonist was pinned against a tree—with a blade or a branch—and died because of massive blood loss. I believe the same thing happened to the hero.

Comment: Not a heck of a lot of information to go on. Can you describe the armour in anyway? Were the two soldier's armour the same or different? Was this a home made compilation or released as a compilation? If it was released as a compilation, what were the other animes and what country was it released in?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/215984/ was one of the other ones on the DVD